# How to extract value without any condition in Regular Expression Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-3.2

Using Bean Shell Sampler, I am getting response data as

```
"tjH9/c05vDE3/Bg2R/fqyR5W7MR31GUmqLb/it36smrsPq4xvM6MhfqP5haE9nzSnzm7+vUXdeKiXzygKtAW4CgEk29c/m8hSvl5isHeFca+V35/AMMKAvjvXq6gbSL5k0ujIymbmnJ2rUgIOHEm6K5YgvJ0ZWAoHcW+Tsk7HqgSYQGz5EBVGsoYVbbd0l/TZEVlbMPYSuKKcEV6ykja8lgmt8Llww9qbgTKwVU6eNVqW7PSjkllJvJtj+j5swbMSZ7/Huisg/deGMo/NlSKnFK1Ym8QTv5agxgKlxWTNboccNoqvgzCOEfn/wG84moKpZiAH4cLagt3kyWVJaix4A=="
```

Note: The above response data is not in Json. I need to extract the same data as is ( above mentioned) using Regular expression / any other expression to pass the same to the subsequent request.

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract **everything** from the parent sampler response you can use the following Regular Expression:

```
(?s)(^.*)
```

Explanation:

- `()` = grouping
- `(?s)` = single line modifier
- `^` = line start
- `.` = wild-card character
- `*` = repetition

More information:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks ! It Worked @Dmitri T